# Flink on EMR cannot access S3 bucket from "flink run" command

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, emr

I'm prototyping the use of AWS EMR for a Flink-based system that we're planning to deploy. My cluster has the following versions:

```
Release label: emr-5.10.0
Hadoop distribution: Amazon 2.7.3
Applications: Flink 1.3.2
```

In the documentation provided by Amazon here: [Amazon flink documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-flink.html)

and the documentation from Flink: [Apache flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/aws.html)

both mention directly using S3 resources as an integrated file system with the `s3://<bucket>/<file>` pattern. I have verified that all the correct permissions are set, I can use the AWS CLI to copy S3 resources to the Master node with no problem, but attempting to start a Flink job using a Jar from S3 does not work.

I am executing the following step:

```
JAR location : command-runner.jar
Main class : None
Arguments : flink run -m yarn-cluster -yid application_1513333002475_0001 s3://mybucket/myapp.jar
Action on failure: Continue
```

The step always fails with

> JAR file does not exist: s3://mybucket/myapp.jar

I have spoken to AWS support, and they suggested having a previous step copy the S3 file to the local Master node and then referencing it with a local path. While this would obviously work, I would rather get the native S3 integration working.

I have also tried using the `s3a` filesystem and get the same result.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download your jar from s3 to be available in the classpath.

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myapp.jar myapp.jar
```

and then run the `run -m yarn-cluster myapp.jar`